# How do I represent a "standard" Javascript object constructor (new ()) in TypeScript when I can't modify the original Javascript?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a project to add type annotations (a .d.ts file) to a large existing Javascript code base. The .d.ts file will live alongside the Javascript, but I can't make any changes to the Javascript to support this project.

In the existing code, there's something like this:

...

```
window.MyGlobal.Service = function () {

}
window.MyGlobal.Service.prototype = {
   baseURL: 'http://...';
}
```

...

With the expectation that we'll later do something like

```
var svc = new window.MyGlobal.Service();
```

I can't figure out how to represent this in TypeScript. I have

```
interface Service {
    baseURL: string;
}
```

But I'm not sure what to put in my Interface for MyGlobal. I've tried

```
interface MyGlobal { 
    Service: Service;
}
```

but I can't use new() on that. I can change it to

```
interface MyGlobal {
    Service(): void;
}
```

and that will let me use new(); but it loses the type information about the Service interface.

Is it possible to handle this situation in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
declare module MyGlobal {
    class Service {
        baseURL: string;
    }   
}

interface Window {
    MyGlobal: { Service: MyGlobal.Service; }    
}

var svc = new window.MyGlobal.Service();
var x = svc.baseURL;
```

Option 2:

```
declare module MyGlobal {
    interface Service {
        baseURL: string;
    }   
}

interface Window {
    MyGlobal: { Service: { new(): MyGlobal.Service } }  
}

var svc = new window.MyGlobal.Service();
var x = svc.baseURL;
```

Comment: Option #1 has the added benefit of being able to create new classes that inherit from (extend) that class in TypeScript!